# How to add a double dictionary to an Array using typeAlias in Swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, type-alias

I use a typeALias to create a 'Double Dictionary' see code.

This dictionary I have to put this in an Array.
Why can't I use "typealias dataPersDict = [[String: Int],[String: Int]]". A comma instead of a semicolon?

```
    typealias dataPersDict = [[String: Int],[String: Int]]
    // type(of: dataPersDict())
    let emplArr = [["emp_id": 1000]:["mgr_id":100]]
    var dataArray = [dataPersDict]()
    dataArray.append(emplArr) // works
    dataArray.append([["emp_id": 1001]:[ "mgr_id": 100]]) // fine
    dataArray.append([["emp_id": 1001],[ "mgr_id": 100]]) // error
```

Comment: Good question, did you solve this?

Comment: Its not really about solving but why? Why can I make a `typealias` using a `comma` because I want a double `dictionary`, but can’t use it in the array. I have to use a `semicolon`, but then gets a double `dictionary` inside a `dictionary`.